# Microsoft Office PowerPoint: Formatting to Fit On Page

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation made by someone else with multiple slides having the text protrude outside of the slide boundaries, so that when I export to PDF the relevant text (or specifically bullet points) are sliced out.

How can I perform a mass resize on all slides such that all text fits on the slides, OR how can I export to PDF whilst being able to view all text?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing the slides is simple but won't help.  When you resize slides, PPT resizes everything ON the slides as well, so whatever was off the slide STAYS off the slide.

I thought of a couple of ways of printing to PDF and preserving the text; alas, none of them worked.  It's PPT, not the printer driver that chops off any text that exceeds the boundaries of the slide.

I suspect you'll need to adjust any off-slide text manually unless you're clever with VBA or some other programming language and can write code to do the adjustment for you.